# Cantidad máxima de números por línea en un messagebox. (C#)

Tags: c#, bucle-for, while, contador

Soy un novato en esto y tengo el siguiente ejercicio: Realizar un programa que escriba y sume la serie 3,6,9....99, teniendo en cuenta que solo puede escribir 7  números por lineal.

El programa me compila correctamente y hace bien el calculo con el siguiente código que he escrito:

```
       int n1, suma;
        string texto;

        n1 = 3;
        suma = 0;
        texto = "";

        while (n1 <= 99)
        {
            texto = texto + n1 + ", ";
            suma = suma + n1;
            n1 = n1 + 3;
            
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Serie; " + "\n" + texto + "\n \n" + "La suma es: " + suma);
```

El problema es que no se como hacer que en el messagebox me aparezca solo 7 números por línea (me aparecen todos en una línea muy larga). Entiendo que deberá ser con un contador for y retornos de carro o algo por el estilo, pero no se como enfocarlo. Si alguien me ayuda le estaré eternamente agradecido.

Answer (score 1):

lo que sucede es que cada 7 numeros debes de hacer un salto de linea para que no se muestre la cadena de texto completa en 1 linea. Espero te sirva este ejemplo.

```cs
int n1 = 3;
int suma = 0;
int salto_de_linea = 0;
string texto = "";

while (n1 <= 99) {
 if (salto_de_linea < 7) {
    texto = texto + n1 + ", ";
    suma = suma + n1;
    n1 = n1 + 3;
 }
 else {
    texto += "\n";
    suma = suma + n1;
    n1 = n1 + 3;
    salto_de_linea = 0;
 }
    salto_de_linea++;
}
MessageBox.Show("Serie: " + "\n" + texto + "\n \n" + "La suma es: " + suma);
```